# Replace Html tag <td> in the table with a html tag @html.textboxfor(m =>m.something) or html.dropdownlistfor(m=>m.something) for rowediting in JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to build an MVC Students details storage and retrieval web app,
problem comes when it comes to editing.
so the table code is like this

```
<div class="centered">
    <table class="table" id="studentlistTable">
        <tr class="header ">
            <th hidden="hidden">ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
            <th>Editing</th>
            <th>Deletion</th>

        </tr>
        @{
            foreach (var x in Model.lstStudent)
            {

            <tr id ="@x.ID">
                <td id="colSID" hidden="hidden">@x.ID</td>

                <td id="tdname">@x.name </td>
                <td id="tdage">@x.age</td>
                <td id="tdgender">@x.gender</td>
                <td id="tdcountry">@x.country</td>
                <td id="tdstate">@x.state</td>
                <td id="tdaddress">@x.address</td>
                <td id="tddob">@x.dob.Day/@x.dob.Month/@x.dob.Year</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="btnEdit" value="Edit" onclick="editRow(this)"></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" /></td>
            </tr>
            }
        }

    </table>
```

and in the editRow(this) method, I'm doing something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function editRow(row) {
    if (confirm("Are you Sure you want to Edit?")) {
        var rid = $(row).closest('tr').id;
        alert(1);
        $("#tdname").replaceWith( "<td>  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.txtStudentName, new { @Id = "txtname" }) </td>");
        $("#tdage").replaceWith("<td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.txtsage, new { @Id = "txtage", @type = "number" }) </td>");
        $("#tdaddress").replaceWith("<td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.txtsaddress, new { @Id = "txtaddress" }) </td>");
        $("#tdgender").replaceWith("<td>    @Html.Label("Male : ") @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.GenderID, "1", new { @checked = "checked" }) @Html.Label("Female : ")  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.GenderID, "2") </td>");
        $("#tdcountry").replaceWith("<td> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.CountryID, new SelectList(Model.ddlCountry, "c_id", "c_name"), new { @Id = "ddlCountry", }) </td>");
        $("#tdstate").replaceWith("<td >@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.StateID, new SelectList(Model.ddlState, "s_id", "s_name"), new { @Id = "ddlCountry" }) </td>");
        $("#tddob").replaceWith("<td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.dob, new { @type = "date", Id = "txtdatepicker" }) </td>");



    }
}
```

and I'm getting an error that "missing ) in the argument list".

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in Advance

Comment: First of all, that error is not stupid, it tells you what to look for. Second, where are you getting this error? Is it an server error or a client error? Also, could you post the entire error?

Comment: Lol, I'm a bit frustrated! Sorry for that, the error is on the first replaceWith statement for id tdname.

Comment: What does the rendered javascript look like? (without the razor code). If this contains `"`, that might be the problem.

Comment: The rendered javascript looks like


$("#tdname").replaceWith( "<td>  <input id="txtStudentName" name="txtStudentName" type="text" value="" /> </td>");

Comment: it contains alot of double quotes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your rendered string contains multiple double quotes. A solution would be to use single quotes to define your original string.

Like so:

```
$("#tdname").replaceWith('<td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.txtStudentName, new { @Id = "txtname" }) </td>');
```

Comment: Thanks Man!! Worked Fine Now! As in just that statement, Got some new errors now! :(

Comment: Glad I could help, feel free to create a new question for the new errors. Consider marking this answer as the solution so other users might find this as well.

Comment: Sorry Man, My Rep is too less to make do anything!

Answer (score 1):

It will be a good approach if you add both display text and control in td from server side.

In your scenario you can add span with text  and a span with controls(initially hidden) in td.In Display Mode you could only display span Text and in Edit Mode you could hide span and display input control and vice versa.

**For Example**

// **HTML**

```
<div class="centered">
    <table class="table" id="studentlistTable">
        <tr class="header ">
            <th hidden="hidden">ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
            <th>Editing</th>
            <th>Deletion</th>
        </tr>
            @{
                foreach (var x in Model.lstStudent)
                {


        <tr id ="@x.ID">
            <td id="colSID" hidden="hidden">@x.ID</td>
            <td id="tdname">
                <span class='spanRec'>@x.name </span> <span class='spanControl' style="display:none">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.txtStudentName, new { @Id = "txtname" }) </span> 
            </td>
            <td id="tdage">
                <span class='spanRec'>@x.age</span> <span class='spanControl' style="display:none">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.txtsage, new { @Id = "txtage", @type = "number" })</span> 
            </td>
            <td id="tdgender">
                <span class='spanRec'>@x.gender</span><span class='spanControl' style="display:none">@Html.Label("Male : ") @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.GenderID, "1", new { @checked = "checked" }) @Html.Label("Female : ")  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.GenderID, "2")</span> 
            </td>
            <td id="tdcountry">
                <span class='spanRec'>@x.country</span><span class='spanControl' style="display:none"> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.CountryID, new SelectList(Model.ddlCountry, "c_id", "c_name"), new { @Id = "ddlCountry", })</span> 
            </td>
            <td id="tdstate">
                <span class='spanRec'>@x.state</span><span class='spanControl' style="display:none">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.StateID, new SelectList(Model.ddlState, "s_id", "s_name"), new { @Id = "ddlCountry" })</span> 
            </td>
            <td id="tdaddress">
                <span class='spanRec'>@x.address</span><span class='spanControl' style="display:none">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.txtsaddress, new { @Id = "txtaddress" })</span> 
            </td>
            <td id="tddob">
                <span class='spanRec'> @x.dob.Day/@x.dob.Month/@x.dob.Year</span><span class='spanControl' style="display:none">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.dob, new { @type = "date", Id = "txtdatepicker" })</span> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btnEdit" value="Edit" onclick="editRow(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" />
                </td>
            </tr>
                }
            }


        </table>
</div>
```

// **JavaScript Code**

```
 function editRow(row) {
        if (confirm("Are you Sure you want to Edit?")) {
            var rid = $(row).closest('tr').id;
            alert(1);
             $(row).closest('tr .spanRec').css{'display','none'};
             $(row).closest('tr .spanControl').css{'display','block'};
        }
    }
```

Comment: His code should work perfectly fine if the server code is rendered in the javascript.

Comment: @Jerodev I agree. Thanks, buddy.

Comment: I didn't think @Html rendered if it was inside a string. I believe the string needs to be escaped to allow that area to render does it not? Something like + \@Html.thing +

Comment: No, @Html will render anywhere in your `cshtml` page. If you don't want it to render, you need to use a double at sign, like so: `@@html`.